# What is first 8 bytes of anchor generated instruction data?

Tags: anchor, solana-program, anchor-client

I am passing two `u32` argument to the instruction. They are appearing at the end but not sure about the first 8 bytes of the instruction data.Another question maybe similar to this how anchor determines which function on the program to call, is it passed in this first 8 bytes of data ?

https://i.ibb.co/8xCGXmb/Screenshot-from-2023-02-17-10-55-42.png Image of an instruction data base58 decoded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption is correct. The first 8 bytes together form the `method identifier` which Anchor uses internally to determine what instruction to invoke. The method identifier is a unique id for each instruction and is derived from its method name and namespace.

You can find a more robust description in the source code documentation [here](https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/37cc99c2b6c24e2bf03ff9d58ed451deb586ffef/lang/syn/src/codegen/program/dispatch.rs#L34).